# pfSense unable to LDAP bind to Active Directory Server

Tags: active-directory, openvpn, ldap, pfsense

I've been instructed to setup an OpenVPN Server on our local pfSense VM. I've combed over tutorials and guides, netgate, openvpn documentation and I feel I must be missing something.

I've tested the AD Servers ability to bind using ldp.exe*
I can also see my various "Authentication Containers" using the [Select a container] button. (Meaning the user I'm using to authenticate to the AD Server is able to authenticate).

However when using Diagnostics>Authentication screen I fail to authenticate and receive the error in my logs: `/diag_authentication.php: ERROR! Either LDAP search failed, or multiple users were found.`

I feel like my issue is stemming from my entire lack of knowledge on this subject... also in my LDAP Server settings:

LDAP Server Settings on pfSense:

Hostname or IP Address: `10.x.x.x` (IP of AD Domain Controller)

Port Value: `389`

Transport: `TCP-Standard`

Peer Cert Auth: Cert Authority I created for this purpose in pfSense

Protocol Version: `3`

Server Timeout: `45`

Search Scope: `Entire Subtree`

BASE DN: `DC=mydomain,DC=local`

Auth Containers: `CN=Users;DC=mydomain,DC=local`

Extended Query: `memberOf=CN=VPNUsers,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local`

I really think my extended query is wrong and this is what's causing my problem.
At one point i had it working it seemed but I managed to break it again?

Variations of extended query I've tried:

```
memberOf=CN=VPNUsers;CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local

memberOf=CN=VPNUsers;CN=Builtin,DC=mydomain,DC=local

memberOf=CN=VPNUsers;CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=mydomain,DC=local
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is wrong:

```
memberOf=CN=VPNUsers;CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local
memberOf=CN=VPNUsers;CN=Builtin,DC=mydomain,DC=local
memberOf=CN=VPNUsers;CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=mydomain,DC=local
```

I don't think you should use `;` but use `,` instead.

Also here:

```
Auth Containers: CN=Users;DC=mydomain,DC=local
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot in a little bit! Thanks for the help.

Comment: `memberOf=CN=VPNUsers,CN=Builtin,DC=mydomain,DC=local` did the trick. Thanks a ton.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help ;)